# Zeroconf not found any service

Tags: python, iot, nodemcu, zeroconf, mdns

I started to test zeroconf to implement the discovery feature in a plugin I'm developing. At the beginning it was working good, but a few weeks ago it isn't showing any available service.

I thought it was problem of my device, but Arduino IDE is showing the mDNS service (I'm using few nodemcu devices).

So now I don't know where is the problem. In the zeroconf github recommended me to use wireshark to know what happen in the traffic, however I don't see anything unusual on it. [Here](http://txt.do/dantz) is the full log.

I've test in differents environments (windows and linux) and both shows me the same results (not services)

So now I'm thinking it could be problem of zeroconf. There someone who can point me what could be the nexts steps to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this](https://github.com/jstasiak/python-zeroconf/issues/85) github issue, the problem was related with **natifaces**, the solution is

uninstall netifaces: `pip uninstall netifaces`

and install version 0.10.4

`pip install netifaces==0.10.4`

after that you should see your mDNS services again

**EDIT**: Netifaces 0.10.6 already solve this issue